# Distinguishing projective collineations with/without an underlying field-automorphism

Tags: field-theory, projective-geometry

Given a projective space with standard coordinates over a field. A collineation is (when I understand it correctly) a projective linear transformation of the coordinates, followed by an automorphism of the field. E.g. in the one-dimensional case over $C$ a collineation could be written as either $z \rightarrow \frac{az + b}{cz+d}$ (:= linear projective) or $z \rightarrow \frac{a\bar{z} + b}{c\bar{z}+d}$ (:= linear anti-projective), $a,b,c,d \in C$ where $z$ denotes the non-homogenous coordinate as in $(z,1)$.

Suppose in the one-dimensional case over $C$ a collineation $\phi$ is given by three points and their images: $\phi: ABC \rightarrow A'B'C'$. According to the fundamental theorem $\phi$ is uniquely defined.
Is it now possible to determine whether the automorphism over $C$  is the identity or not, i.e. whether the collineation is projective or anti-projective?

How about the 2- or 3-dimensional case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A projective transformation in a one-dimensional projective space is uniquely defined by three points and their images. But if the underlying field has a non-trivial automorphism, then every such triple might as well be the result of a projective transformation (possibly identity) combined with that automorphism.

So given three points and their images in $\mathbb{CP}^1$, there are actually *two* collineations between them, one projective and the other anti-projective.

The same holds for higher dimensions, and other fields, with $d+2$ points (in general position) for $\mathbb{KP}^d$ defining a projective transformation, and all automorphisms of the field $\mathbb K$ providing separate alternatives for collieations.

Comment: This seems very logical, but how about the mapping $f: z \rightarrow \bar{z}$? The anti-projective collineation is clearly: identity+complex conjugation. Which projective collineation (without complex conjugation) would then belong to this mapping?

Comment: @Gerard: It depends on the defining points. If you define $z\mapsto\bar z$ via $0\mapsto0,1\mapsto 1,2\mapsto2$ then the identity $z\mapsto z$ would be the projective counterpart. If, on the other hand, you define it using $i\mapsto-i,1+i\mapsto1-i,3+2i\mapsto3-2i$ then the projective counterpart would be $z\mapsto\frac{(9+i)z-16i}{2iz+9-i}$.